# Change a date/time string to a timestamp in PHP using a Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, timestamp

I'm struggling with a RegEx to change a date/time string to a timestamp. The format of the string is `'d/m/Y \a\t g:ia'` (e.g. 15/06/2012 at 6:00pm).

I need to do this to ensure that a date is not in the past.

I can do the date part (just `'d/m/Y'`) using the following code, but it's the rest that I am struggling with. Thanks.

```
$expires = preg_replace("/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/", "\\3-\\2-\\1" , $poll['poll_expired']);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a regex ? why not construct a DateTime object and use `getTimestamp` ?

Comment: Will do in the future, but I couldn't use what I didn't know existed. Always thought regex was the way to go with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you do something like this?

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y \a\t g:ia', ' 15/06/2012 at 6:00pm');
$expires = $date->format('U');
```

(Not tested but you get the idea.)

Comment: He can and he should :) Don't know, why some tries to solve _everything_ with regex...

Comment: +1 exactly what my comment suggests ... (note the [`getTimestamp` method](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php))

Comment: Many thanks @Josh - I was unaware of this method, but it is much easier than regex. Other then substituting the date with the variable that held it, your example worked perfectly.